# How to convert exponential number String to an integer number String

Tags: java, string, integer, exponential

What is the best/fastest way to convert an exponential integer number of String type (e.g. `"2.4490677E7"`) to an integer number String (e.g. `"24490677"`) in Java?

**Edit:** The input is known to always be an integer.

My current proposal is as follows (using `org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils` from Apache Commons):

```
String input = "2.4490677E7";
String res = null;
Double d = NumberUtils.toDouble(input);
if (d != 0.0d) {
   // we have a double number here
   res = String.format("%d", d.intValue());
}
```

Comment: What is the problem then?

Comment: What should be the result of 2.4112E2 *conversion*?

Comment: If you need precision to be untouched, then you could use BigDecimal to read the string, and then convert it to int value.

Comment: Agree with @KrzysztofCichocki BigDecimal class is the way to go

Comment: @Amit I was looking for a more elegant way than suggested.

Comment: @PM77-1 this would be a false input as input is known to be integer (I forgot to state that).

Answer (score 2):

If you need precision to be untouched, then you could use BigDecimal to read the string, and then convert it to int value

Comment: `new BigDecimal(input).toPlainString()`

Comment: the convert to int part, is not needed in his case

Comment: @JoopEggen This would be my preferred solution.

Answer (score 2):

hi we can get from this "2.4490677E7" to this "24490677"
here is the code

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String value = "2.4490677E7";
    BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(value);
    System.out.println(result.longValue());
}
}
```

output will be : 24490677

i hope you are looking for this..
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

what about

```
Integer res = ((Double) Double.parseDouble(input)).intValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest the best approach.
It should take care of the precision. If the string is a decimal value the precision after decimal needs to be precised.

```
 String str = "123456789.0111222333444555666777888999E10";
 try {
     /** DOUBLE **/
     double doubleVal = Double.parseDouble(str);//still uses 'E'
     System.out.println("Pure Double: "+ doubleVal);// Pure Double: 1.23456789011122227E18
     System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("0000000000.00000000000000").format(doubleVal));//1234567890111222270.00000000000000
     String plainStrFrmDouble = BigDecimal.valueOf(doubleVal).toPlainString();
     System.out.println("From double: " + plainStrFrmDouble);//From double: 1234567890111222270
     //convert to desired decimal format
     System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("0.0000000").format(Double.parseDouble(plainStrFrmDouble)));//1234567890111222270.0000000


     /** BIG DECIMAL **/
     String plainStrFrmBigDec = new BigDecimal(str).toPlainString();
     System.out.println("From bigdecimal: " + plainStrFrmBigDec);         //From bigdecimal:      1234567890111222333.444555666777888999
     System.out.println("From bigdecimalNonplain" + new BigDecimal(str));//From bigdecimalNonplain1234567890111222333.444555666777888999 *The most PRECISE way*
 } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
     System.err.println("Error while formatting.");
 }
```

So, I think, new BigDecimal(str) should suffice.